# How to create a stacked picture from 2 segments?

Tags: html, css

I've coded a personal website. I used a background picture as a head page and my portrait as an avatar. My favorite interface is likely Linkedin profile. But I cannot stack two pics together.

I used bootstrap 3.
My html:

```
<div class="head-image">
    </div>
    <img src="assets/images/ava_Do.png" alt="ava_Do" id="ava_image">
```

My CSS:

```
 body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.head-image {
  /* Full height */
  height: 35%; 
  background-image: url(../assets/images/image.png);
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 0;
}

#ava_image {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100px;
  top: 20%
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I want to stack them like a Linkedin profile.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you mean you want the items stacked on the z-index.

The markup to display the background image and the portrait overlay:

```
<div class="head-background">
  <img class="head-image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Placeholder">
</div>
```

The styles to position them correctly:

```
.head-background {
  background: #666;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.head-image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-75%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I've attached a link to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6uv9mkbr/) as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in your html  :

```
<div class="head-image">
    <img src="assets/images/ava_Do.png" alt="ava_Do" id="ava_image">
</div>
```

You had badly closed the tag maybe : `<div> </div>`